# Powershell date comparison not returning expected results

Tags: datetime, comparison, powershell-2.0

Not sure if I am doing something wrong but I am not getting the results I would expect.

I have the following function to return a UTC date/time value so I can request for both local and remote machines.

```
function Get-UTCTime {
     Param([string]$computername=$env:computername)

    $utc = Get-WmiObject win32_utctime -ComputerName $computername 

        return $sysdt = ([string]$utc.month + "/" + [string]$utc.day + "/" + [string]$utc.year + " " + [string]$utc.hour + ":" + [string]$utc.minute + ":" + [string]$utc.second)

}

      [datetime]$lsysdt = Get-UTCTime "."
        Write-Host "Local:" $lsysdt

      [datetime]$rsysdt = Get-UTCTime $computer 
        Write-Host "Remote:" $rsysdt.addminutes(6)

        $tester1 = $lsysdt - $rsysdt 
        $tester2 = New-TimeSpan -Start $lsysdt -End $rsysdt 

        Write-Host "Tester 1" $tester1 
        Write-Host "Tester 2" $tester2
```

My results are as follows

```
Local: 6/21/2013 6:06:43 PM
Remote: 6/21/2013 6:12:45 PM
Tester 1 -00:00:02
Tester 2 00:00:02
```

You can see I have a 6 minute and 2 second difference in the times but the resulting value returned only displays seconds.

I expanded all properties on tester1 variable and still don't see that it includes minutes.

```
Ticks             : -20000000
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : -2
TotalDays         : -2.31481481481481E-05
TotalHours        : -0.000555555555555556
TotalMilliseconds : -2000
TotalMinutes      : -0.0333333333333333
TotalSeconds      : -2
```

what simple little concept am I missing with the datetime comparison?

Answer (score 0):

oh Gosh... I see my issue.

my addminutes() method was only being added to my host out put and not the actual stored variable.

Sigh... to late when I was working on it.

```
[datetime]$lsysdt = Get-UTCTime "."
    Write-Host "Local:" $lsysdt

[datetime]$rsysdt = Get-UTCTime $computer 
    Write-Host "Remote:" $rsysdt.addminutes(-3)

    $dtdiff = New-TimeSpan -Start $lsysdt -End $rsysdt.addminutes(-3)
    $dtdiffmin = $($dtdiff.TotalMinutes).ToString("n", $dtdiffmin) 
    if ($dtdiffmin -lt [int]-3 -and $dtdiffmin -lt [int] 3) { 
            $timeok = $true 
            } 
            else {
                $timeok = $false
            } 

    if ($timeok -eq $false) {
        Write-Host "Remote System Time Ok:" $dtdiffmin
```

Comment: This was my resulting code after I figured out my dummy move. (Edited above.)

Answer (score 0):

```
     function Get-UTCTime {
     Param([string]$computer)
     $computer=$env:COMPUTERNAME

$utc = Get-WmiObject win32_utctime -ComputerName $computer

    return $sysdt = ([string]$utc.month + "/" + [string]$utc.day + "/" + 
    [string]$utc.year + " " + [string]$utc.hour + ":" + [string]$utc.minute + ":" + [string]$utc.second)

    }

  [datetime]$lsysdt = Get-UTCTime "."
    Write-Host "Local:" $lsysdt

  [datetime]$rsysdt = Get-UTCTime $computer
    Write-Host "Remote:" $rsysdt.addminutes(6)
    $newRsysdt = $rsysdt.addminutes(6)

    $tester1 = $lsysdt - $newRsysdt
    $tester2 = New-TimeSpan -Start $lsysdt -End $newRsysdt

    Write-Host "Tester 1" $tester1 
    Write-Host "Tester 2" $tester2
```

Comment: You get the point:) Just saw your self-answer after posting mine.

Comment: You probably need a little change on param part too. I run your script and it first stuck on that area saying " Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty.
s not null or empty and then try the command again." Hence the change in my script.

Comment: The way you get utc time is good. Just want to share with u another way: through PS cmdlet. eg. (get-date).ToUniversalTime().month